# Prevent Git Extensions from doing continuous git status requests

Tags: git, git-extensions

When I have Git Extensions open and am also using git from bash, I frequently run into an error:

> fatal: Unable to create '/home/ldombek/code/navkit/.git/index.lock': File exists.
>
> Another git process seems to be running in this repository [...]

Usually the same operation succeeds when retrying immediately afterwards.

I suspect the behaviour is due to Git Extensions continuously getting git status updates as seen in its command log window.

Is there a way to suppress these status updates or make them much less frequent?

Comment: How about [filing a bug report](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues)?

Comment: BTW isn't it [this feature](https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#plugins-periodic-background-fetch)?

Comment: @kostix It isn't the fetch feature as the only command that is run is "git status --porcelain ..."

Answer (score 1):

That should be the setting "Show number of changed files on commit button". See https://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#git-extensions